# Bluestacks not connecting to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb, bluestacks

I am new to android programming and I am fed up with the slowness of the built-in AVD system. I have bluestacks installed and would like to use it instead. It did not appear in the android devices list when I checked on eclipse, so I did a little research and attempted the `adb connect localhost:5555` command in the cmd. It said that it was connected successfully, but still didn't work. I am thoroughly stumped and would like a lot of help.

Comment: Check [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) instead.

Comment: Your first issue is that you are using Eclipse over Android Studio.

Comment: I use eclipse because i find it easier to stick with a IDE i am familliar with instead of having a new ide for each language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download). It's way faster than AVD, can test on multiple devices and versions easily, and easier to use than Bluestacks.

Comment: Thank you very much adao7000 and @khalafnt . You saved me from giving up entirely